# Difference between Error functions

Tags: r, arbitrary-precision

In Mathematica there is an option [see this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136018/difference-between-erf-functions) to calculate the difference between two error functions. However, I have not yet found any thing similar in R.

I need to calculate things like Erf(1604.041) - Erf(3117.127) and get a non zero value...

Comment: R is principally a numerical computation system. Wolfram Alpha gives the result to be approximately 4e-1117421. This is far beyond the scope of numerical precision to even represent, let alone compute. The minimum value of a double is about 2e-308, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can come close to the result of 4e-1117421 given in the comment by @James.
First, the error function can be computed like this in R:

```
1 - 2 * pnorm(-sqrt(2) * x)
```

However, this will give you numerical zeros due to floating point precision. Fortunately, `pnorm` can return the log of the p-values. You can then exponentiate it using arbitrary precision numbers:

```
library(Rmpfr)
2 * exp(mpfr(pnorm(-sqrt(2) * 1604.041, log.p = TRUE), precBits = 32)) -
  2 * exp(mpfr(pnorm(-sqrt(2) * 3117.127, log.p = TRUE), precBits = 32)) 
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  32   bits 
#[1] 4.2826176801e-1117421
```

(Note that you get only floating point precision for the log-p-values.)

However, I wonder in which kind of application such a precision is necessary. It's essentially a zero value.

**Edit:** And I've just found out that Rmpfr offers an implementation of the complementary error function. You can simply do this:

```
erfc(mpfr(3117.127, precBits = 32)) - erfc(mpfr(1604.041, precBits = 32))
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  32   bits 
#[1] -4.2854514871e-1117421
```

Comment: Nice one. I had tried using Rmpfr but ended up crashing it!

Comment: Numerical integration... I need to numerical integrate the ratio of the difference between two error functions that can take this values

Comment: I don't believe that this is the way forward then. (And I doubt that it makes a difference whether you integrate 0 or 4e-1117421.)